Why does this optimistic lock fails?
I was experimenting with optimistic locks and wrote this for hset, under heavy load of events trying to update the same key, observed TxFailedErr(redis: transaction failed) from redis client which is part of tx.go, not too often but for my use case, it should not happen ideally. What is wrong here? Also can I see anywhere what has caused this transaction to fail? The VM I am running this has enough memory btw.
func hset(ctx context.Context, c *client, key, field string, object Revisioner) (newObj Revisioner, err error) {

    txf := func(tx *redis.Tx) error {
        // Get the current value or some state of the key
        current, err := tx.HGet(ctx, key, field).Result()
        if err != nil && err != redis.Nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("hget: %w", err)
        }
        // Compare revisions for optimistic locking
        ok, err := object.RevisionCompare([]byte(current))
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("revision compare: %w", err)
        }
        if !ok {
            return ErrModified
        }

        // Create a new object with a new revision
        newObj = object.WitNewRev()

        data, err := json.Marshal(newObj)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("marshalling: %w", err)
        }

        // Execute the HSET command within the transaction
        _, err = tx.TxPipelined(ctx, func(pipe redis.Pipeliner) error {
            pipe.HSet(ctx, key, field, string(data))
            return nil
        })
        return err
    }

    // Execute the transaction with the Watch method
    err = c.rc.Watch(ctx, txf, key)
    if err == redis.TxFailedErr {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("transaction error: %w", err)
    } else if err != nil {
        return nil, ErrModified
    }

    return newObj, nil
}


Do you have any more info of transaction error ?

@Mathew that's the issue, the redis go client only throw this error. Even in redis logs at debug level I could only find connections getting accepted and closed. Is there any other place I can find txn failure logs?
